# geolocation coordinates of users from tweets

Tags: python, twitter, geolocation, tweepy, twitter-api-v2

I give my code as in the below `MWE` which works fine.

```py
import tweepy

BEARER = "my-bearer-token"

class MyListener(tweepy.StreamingClient):
    def on_data(self, data):
        try:
            with open('python.json', 'a') as f:
                f.write(str(data))
                print(data)
                return True

        except BaseException as e:
            print("Error on_data: %s" % str(e))

    def on_connect(self):
        print('Connected..!')
        
    def on_error(self, status):
        print(status)
        return True
```

And I define the following rules to get location specific data:

```
stream = MyListener(BEARER)
stream.add_rules(tweepy.StreamRule('place:Lagos OR place:Abuja has:geo'))
stream.filter()
```

And successfully retrieved the following data (from `print(data)` statement):

```
$ python tweetify.py
Connected..!
b'{"data":{"id":"1559694255035138048","text":"@halimahthebird N*gga the next day "},"matching_rules":[{"id":"1559694230766895104","tag":""}]}'
b'{"data":{"id":"1559694261976764421","text":"@O_luwatomiwa Mental illness I tell you \xf0\x9f\x98\x82"},"matching_rules":[{"id":"1559694230766895104","tag":""}]}'
b'{"data":{"id":"1559694339709730816","text":"@elonmusk He gon buy united at the dip"},"matching_rules":[{"id":"1559694230766895104","tag":""}]}'
...
```

Good that the filter works, those tweets came from the defined place in rule.

***Question**

But I want to retrieve the location coordinates `[LONG, LAT]` not the tweets. I added the operator `has:geo` but not sure how to retrieve the coordinates.

Comment: You need to add fields and expansion parameters to the request to expand the Tweet objects you receive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to set your code to request the fields you need, something like:

```py
class MyListener(tweepy.StreamingClient):
    def on_data(self, data):
      data_obj = json.loads(data.decode('utf8'))
      print(json.dumps(data_obj,indent=2))
      return True

    def on_connect(self):
      print('Connected..!')
        
    def on_error(self, status):
      print(status)
      return True


stream = MyListener(BEARER)
stream.add_rules(tweepy.StreamRule('place:London OR place:Paris has:geo', tag="london-paris"))
stream.filter(tweet_fields=["geo","created_at","author_id"],place_fields=["id","geo","name","country_code","place_type","full_name","country"],expansions=["geo.place_id"])
```

Lat/lon information would be in the `includes.places.geo.bbox` object.

Comment: OMG..! Now I understand lots of things I misunderstood. Many thanks.